# JDK environment variable ( Ubuntu 12.04) with tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, ubuntu

In Ubuntu,i set jdk environment(JAVA_HOME,JRE_HOME), and java -version can use.
but i can start up tomcat. some info :

- Neither the JAVA_HOME nor the JRE_HOME environment variable is defined
- At least one of these environment variable is needed to run this program

environment set **/etc/profile**

```
JAVA_HOME=/opt/jvm/java/jdk1.7.0_25
JRE_HOME=/opt/jvm/java/jdk1.7.0_25/jre
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME
export JAVA_HOME
export JRE_HOME
export PATH
```

logs

```
sunshanming@sunshanming-vm1:~$ sudo /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/bin/startup.sh 
[sudo] password for sunshanming: 
Neither the JAVA_HOME nor the JRE_HOME environment variable is defined
At least one of these environment variable is needed to run this program
sunshanming@sunshanming-vm1:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/opt/jvm/java/jdk1.7.0_25
sunshanming@sunshanming-vm1:~$ echo $JRE_HOME
/opt/jvm/java/jdk1.7.0_25/jre
sunshanming@sunshanming-vm1:~$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to set the variables in `setenv.sh` in tomcats `bin` folder. Thats where you specify the environment for tomcat.

Just create this file in *tomcat/bin/setenv.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/
export CATALINA_OUT=/var/log/tomcat/catalina.out
export CATALINA_PID=/var/log/tomcat/catalina.pid
```

You can also specify other env. vars for you application there.

**Note:** They don't create this file by default. Otherwise it would be overwritten on an update.

**Update because of your comment:**

The problem is that the `/etc/profile` is not loaded if you use `sudo`.

You can test it like this:

```
# Write a variable SMALLTEST into the profile file
sudo su -c "echo \"export SMALLTEST=Hello World\" >> /etc/profile"

# create a small script (like your startup.sh) that read the variable
echo "echo Variable is set to: \$SMALLTEST" > smalletst
chmod  +x smalletst 

# Execute the script with sudo
sudo ./smalletst 
Variable is set to:
```

And you see that the env. var is not set.

**Update 2:**

If you like to let your tomcat run as a service, you should have a look to the `/opt/tomcat/bin/daemon.sh` script. This you can put ti `/etc/init.d/tomcat` and specify your env. in the setenv.sh.

Comment: use this way,when i change jdk, i need edit two file.how use one file? thanks for your answer.

Comment: sudo is not reading from /etc/profile. I adjusted the answer to that

Answer (score 1):

With Ubuntu you don't have to modify anything for running tomcat, if you use the packages that ship with the Ubuntu repo.

Just type `sudo apt-get install tomcat7`. That will install `tomcat7` with all the needed dependencies.

I recommend to not install *anything* manually(without the package system), if you don't have to.

Comment: I use oracle jdk. i install jdk and tomcat use zip.gz and use  _sudo apt-get install tomcat7_ this dependencies contain _openjdk_ and not _oracle jdk_ thanks for you answer

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple actually.

In startup.sh and shutdown.sh, just provide the JAVA_HOME system variable value -

**export JAVA_HOME**="/home/mxdev/java_stack/jdk1.8.0_77"